# ASP.NET MVC - Applying Html.ActionLink to an existing href

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Basically, I'm just trying to change the `href` attribute to be the result of the `ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Dashboard", new { }, new { @class = "nav-link active" })
<a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">
    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></div>
Home
</a>
```

If I replaced the `index.html` with `@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Dashboard")`, then what happens is the HTML is not formed correctly.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard"), sorry this can be closed.  Of course as soon as I ask I find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this code will work as you want it to. You don't have to use @Html.ActionLink

```
<a class="nav-link active" href="Dashboard/Index">
    <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></div>
Home
</a>
```